# Which of these set mothods will add a key to a set?

Tags: java, hashmap, set, maps, key

Which of these following methods will add a key to a set?
The add method, the get method, the set method, the put method, or none of these methods.

Comment: @JonKittell there is no code its just asking which method adds a key to a set. Its supposed to be multiple choice but the formatting wouldn't let me.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. `Map`s have keys but `Set`s do not. You add to a `Map` using `put` and add to a `Set` using `add`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *add* method. According to the [`Set.add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) Javadoc,

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present (optional operation).